# Unable to launch pidgin

Tags: apt, pidgin

Using `pidgin` from the command-line or launching it via the indicator is not working. I've tried reinstalling it, but the issue persists:

```
$ pidgin
The program 'pidgin' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install pidgin
$ sudo apt-get install pidgin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
pidgin is already the newest version.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

How can this be fixed?

**Update:** removing pidgin-sipe did not help remove the diversion (see answers below). Doing `sudo dpkg-divert --remove /usr/bin/pidgin`, and then reinstalling the pidgin package fixed it.

Comment: have you tried to start it like this: `/usr/bin/pidgin`? Or reinstall it via `apt-get install --reinstall -f pidgin` if it isn't there.

Comment: what is the output of `whereis pidgin` and `type pidgin`? Also, the output of `dpkg -L pidgin`.

Comment: ``/usr/bin/pidgin`` isn't there, just ``/usr/bin/pidgin.orig``. Using reinstall didn't help. Output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6586027/

Hm, the diversion looks funky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in http://paste.ubuntu.com/6586027/:

```
/usr/bin/pidgin
diverted by pidgin-sipe to: /usr/bin/pidgin.orig
```

Another package called pidgin-sipe diverted the original `/usr/bin/pidgin` to `/usr/bin/pidgin.orig`. I recommend to purge this package by:

```
sudo apt-get purge pidgin-sipe
```

and then mv pidgin.orig to pidgin:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/pidgin.orig /usr/bin/pidgin
```

Comment: I need the package though as it gives the ability to use Pidgin on a Microsoft Lync network. Is it possible to fix this while keeping SIPE (and a decently recent version of it; the one in repositories is kind of outdated)?

Comment: You can still start pidgin by typing: `pidgin.orig` without purging the other package.

Comment: Use the divert fix in the original problem and purge all the packages. Install pidgin, and start it. Add the pidgin-sipe repo and install while pidgin is running. Quit pidgin and restart it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's a package diversion that renames `/usr/bin/pidgin` to `/usr/bin/pidgin.orig`, for some reason. I can't verify the changelog now (servers are dead) but you may execute pidgin by typing `pidgin.orig`.